# MongoDB aggregate and get mismatched results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, filter, aggregate

Hi everyone i have 2 collections named "members" and "offers" in mongoDB. When a member send an offer to another, my web service saves it to offers collection.

"members" collection is like:

```
[
    {
         "_id": "5ee00pp0ebfd4432145233344",
        "Fname": "John",
        "Lname": "Lastname",
        "Email": "JohnLastName@gmail.com",
    },
    {
         "_id": "yyyy44p0ebfd4432145233355",
        "Fname": "Ashley",
        "Lname": "Lastname",
        "Email": "AshleyLastName@gmail.com",
    },
    {
         "_id": "yyyy44p0ebfd4432145233355",
        "Fname": "Sue",
        "Lname": "Lastname",
        "Email": "SueLastName@gmail.com",
    }
]
```

when John send an offer to Ashley

"offers" collection is like:

```
[
       {
                "_id": "5eea6e62881835271415fd25",                                
                "OfferMail": "JohnLastName@gmail.com",
                "Email": "AshleyLastName@gmail.com",
       }
]
```

Now my question is: How can i get all members except Ashley?

Answer (score 0):

Use the $not operator. For example
db.members.find({"Email" : {"$not" : "AshleyLastName@gmail.com"}})

Comment: The problem is we dont know who sent offers to any user. So we want to use aggregate and project stage.

Answer (score 0):

`````
 db.members.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "offers",
      "localField": "Email",
      "foreignField": "Email",
      "as": "docuentInB"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: { $eq: [{ $size: "$docuentInB" }, 0 ] }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      docuentInB: 0
    }
  }
])````
`````